# How can I change the accent color of checkboxes, sliders, radio buttons and select components

Tags: html, css

I want to change the accent color of checkboxes, sliders, radio buttons and select components.
Is there any easy method for doing so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the new `accent-color` property if you are using [Chrome version 93+](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4752739957473280).

```css
#checkbox {
  accent-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```

This works for checkboxes, sliders and radio buttons. There is currently no way to style the background of options of select components.

Browser support is still [limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color#browser_compatibility) though. It will be supported in the next versions of Firefox and Edge too.

Comment: It's not showing limegreen on my latest version of chrome somehow? Is it my problem?

Comment: You need Chrome version 93, please check in your chrome settings if you have this version

Comment: This is awesome!  Any tips on if/how to customize the checkmark color as well?

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter: hue-rotate` for your inputs is useful

`hue-rotate` is counted in degrees that means that you can use 0-360deg

(This is supported in every browser)

Here's an example:

```css
input {
  filter: hue-rotate(320deg)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked><br>
<input type="radio" checked><br>
<input type="range">
```

Comment: I think using `hue-rotate` is not as good of a solution, because the resulting color depends on the color of the element before styling. On Safari on Mac for example, you get the checkbox in your preferred system color. In my case this is orange (after: light red), whereas my checkboxes in chrome are blue (after: turquoise).

Comment: @3v3ryb0dy tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and it works fine. Which versions are you using

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the color of the input before applying the filter and not the browser version (I'm using Chrome 93 and Safari 14.1.2 btw)
Try setting your accent color in MacOS (System settings > General > Accent color) to something other than blue to reproduce.
These screenshots have been captured on the same machine using your solution: https://imgur.com/a/ltW4D3Q

Comment: @3v3ryb0dy okay