# How to change background color of checkbox in css

Tags: css

I have one checkbox inside div. The div class name is main.I am trying to set the background color to main classname when i checked the checkbox. But not able to set background color to .main classname.

If i checked the checkbox it will be look like below.
[image]

If i unchecked the checkbox it will be look like below.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="main"> 
 <input type="checkbox" id="maincheck">{{item.title}}
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main input[id='maincheck']:checked:after{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

How to achieve using CSS? Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-example-mhvnkb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958117/how-to-change-checkbox-background-color-in-simple-html

Comment: I posted another similar question.. anyway custom checkbox should be styled with separate elements mimicking it and forwarding event to an hidden checkbox

Comment: @DiegoD: I am trying to set background color to .main not for checkbox. Please check my question.

Comment: sorry.. I didn't pay enough attention.. a totally different problem then

Comment: You can use the `accent-color:` [CSS attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) and set it to `green;` or whatever color you would like. Try this: `.main input[id='maincheck']:checked { accent-color: green; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to change the background colour of the checkbox's parent element. This can be rephrased as '*if .main contains a checked checkbox then...*'. In CSS you could use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class to select an element that *has* a certain child:

```css
.main:has(input[id='maincheck']:checked) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="checkbox" id="maincheck">item title
</div>
```

**But note that at the time of writing this is NOT yet supported in Firefox**. (See https://caniuse.com/css-has)

An alternative would be to move the checkbox to before its parent. Then you can use the [next-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) (`+`) to select the div that directly follows a checked checkbox:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

input[id='maincheck'] {
  position: absolute;
}

label[for='maincheck'] {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

input[id='maincheck']:checked+.main {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="maincheck" />
  <div class="main">
    <label for="maincheck">item title</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly change the parent element's style using only CSS, so you'd have to use JavaScript or jQuery.

Here's a JavaScript approach:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Grab the checkbox element
  const checkBox = document.getElementById("maincheck");

  // Grab the main div
  const mainDiv = document.querySelector(".main");

  // Add an event listener for checkbox changes
  checkBox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      // If checked, add the 'checked' class to the main div
      mainDiv.classList.add("checked");
    } else {
      // If unchecked, remove the 'checked' class from the main div
      mainDiv.classList.remove("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  /* Default background color */
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main.checked {
  /* Background color when checkbox is checked */
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="maincheck">Item Title
</div>
```

when you check the checkbox, the background colour of the .main div will change to #ccc, and when you uncheck it, the background will revert to transparent.