# How to change background of parent element with :focus-within if child element selected

Tags: html, css

I tried to select parent element which is the wrapper of my radio button input.
I want to make the wrapper that have background colour using `:focus-within` if the radio button selected.
But seems it didn't work. What's wrong with css code?

```css
.custom-radios div.wrapper {
  display: block;
  background-color: #F8FBFE;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.custom-radios div.wrapper:focus-within input[type=radio]:checked {
  background-color: #4199D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <input type="radio" id="color-1" name="color" value="color-1">
    <label for="color-1">
            <span class="radio-check-icon">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
            </span>
            <div class='radio-value'>
              <div class='radio-label'>
                <img class='radio-image' 
                src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flyingduck92/svgs-collection/main/drinks-logos/sprite.svg"/zzz>
                <p>Green</p>
              </div>
              <div class='radio-info'>
                <div>
                    <small>Limit</small>
                    <p>Rp. 5.000.000</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Fee</small><br>
                  <p>1.1%</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Tenor</small><br>
                  <p>7 Days</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] here please, not on codepen

Comment: Possible duplicate. Sounds like you want to change the background colour of an element containing a checked radio. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77272758/1921385

Comment: @Moob already tried that, but didn't work either on my case also that code is :has not :focus-within. :has not supported on firefox

Comment: Your use of focus-within is incorrect. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within. Furthermore :focus-within won't work where the focussed element is not visible (your radios in your codepen are hidden). See  https://codepen.io/moob/pen/GRPbJKV?editors=0100

Comment: @Moob so the focus-within only work if the element visible?

Comment: @flyingduck92 that's my understanding yes. I expect that if they are visibly hidden in some way other than display:none (such as positioning them outside of the viewport) then they should be focusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:has`:

```css
.custom-radios div.wrapper {
  display: block;
  background-color: #F8FBFE;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.custom-radios div.wrapper:has(input[type=radio]:checked) {
  background-color: #4199D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <input type="radio" id="color-1" name="color" value="color-1">
    <label for="color-1">
            <span class="radio-check-icon">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
            </span>
            <div class='radio-value'>
              <div class='radio-label'>
                <img class='radio-image' 
                src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flyingduck92/svgs-collection/main/drinks-logos/sprite.svg"/zzz>
                <p>Green</p>
              </div>
              <div class='radio-info'>
                <div>
                    <small>Limit</small>
                    <p>Rp. 5.000.000</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Fee</small><br>
                  <p>1.1%</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Tenor</small><br>
                  <p>7 Days</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks man but it seems didn't have support on Firefox

Comment: @flyingduck92 True, but it should soon

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am getting this correctly, you want the wrapper background to change if the radio button is checked, but only as long as the radio button inside the wrapper actually has the focus, i.e. after clicking somewhere else on the site, the background should revert back, even though the radio button is still checked?

You can work around the need for `:has()`, if you put the radio button before the wrapper, and then use the next sibling combinator, `+`.

`:focus-within` will not apply to the wrapper any more, since the radio button was taken out of it - but it is still within `.custom-radios`, so we can apply our "focus demand" on that one:

```css
.custom-radios div.wrapper {
  display: block;
  background-color: #F8FBFE;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.custom-radios:focus-within input[type=radio]:checked + div.wrapper {
  background-color: #4199D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-radios">
  <input type="radio" id="color-1" name="color" value="color-1">
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <label for="color-1">
            <span class="radio-check-icon">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/242518/check-icn.svg" alt="Checked Icon" />
            </span>
            <div class='radio-value'>
              <div class='radio-label'>
                <img class='radio-image' 
                src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flyingduck92/svgs-collection/main/drinks-logos/sprite.svg"/zzz>
                <p>Green</p>
              </div>
              <div class='radio-info'>
                <div>
                    <small>Limit</small>
                    <p>Rp. 5.000.000</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Fee</small><br>
                  <p>1.1%</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <small>Tenor</small><br>
                  <p>7 Days</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: No sir, the background should revert back to white if the radio button is not checked. Apparently, after I check the documentation `:focus-within` only works if the radio button appears on the screen. My case is custom radio button that I set the radio button to `display: none`. Also the radio button not outside the wrapper, its inside the wrapper

Comment: Not sure what the point of involving `:focus-within` is supposed to be to begin with. _"My case is custom radio button that I set the radio button to display: none."_ - that is a very bad idea to begin with, it can lead to the whole thing becoming completely unusable to screen reader users. Go look up ways to hide an element in a screen reader-"friendly" way, without using display:none.